# Can I get a polynomial out of a polynomial division?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, computer-algebra-systems

I have a to divide a thrid degree polynomial by another one,
is it possible for me to get another polynomial out of it?

*By the way, I am working with decimal numbers (floats in 32bits).*

If it is possible, this problem needs to be solved relatively quickly as I plan on using the solution in a videogame, basically every frame.
Let's say the division looks something like this:
$$\frac{ax^3+bx^2+cx+d}{ex^3+fx^2+gx+h}$$
How would you get a polynomial out of it?
Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks in advance.

---

EDIT: So it seems like my problem wasn't properly
explained what i wanted is to get h(x) where
$$h(x)  =\frac{ax^3+bx^2+cx+d}{ex^3+fx^2+gx+h}$$
written as
$$h(x) = jx^3+kx^2+lx+m$$
(or get a higher degree polynomial).

However, as @no lemon no melon said, it turns out that the result of the division of polynomials is not a polynomial but rather a rational function.
So I guess that my question was
*"is the result of a polynomial division a polynomial?"*.

This is really new to me so hopefully this didn't seemed too stupid, again thanks a lot.

Comment: The ratio of two polynomials is not a polynomial. Why exactly do you try to do this (probable XY question) ?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\frac{f}{g}$ gives you a polynomial $h$ of degree $k$.

If degree of $f$ is $3$ and degree of $g$ is $3$.

Then we have $f=gh$. Degree of $f$ is equal to the degree of $g$ plus the degree of $h$.

Hence degree of $h$ must be $0$, the constant polynomial.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But how would i do to compute h(x) in the form $$ex^3+fx^3+gx+h$$

Comment: $h(x)$ would always be of the form $0\cdot x^3 + 0\cdot x^2+0\cdot x +h =h$ for some constant $h$ as stated by Siong

Comment: If it is a polynomial. It's a constant. In general, it is a rational function plus a constant, not a polynomial. You might like to describe more what you are trying to do